# SQL output activity not have

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have 3 tables called `Classes`, `Courses` and `Activitys`.

The `Courses` and `Classes` tables have the columns `Id` and `Name`.
The `Activitys` table has the columns `ClassId` and `CourseId`.

How do I show a list where I print the courses that the class doesnt have?

Output should look like this:

> **-Class-    -Missing class-**
>
> class1     course1
>
> class1     course3
>
> class2     class 2
>
> CLass 1 only have course 2
>
> CLass 2  have course 1 and course 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT Name FROM Courses WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Activitys WHERE ClassId = <Id> );
```

From the scratch of my head I'd try that. That should give you all the Courses that the chosen Class does not have.

`<Id>` in the end has to be the Id of the class you want to check for.

Comment: The problem is that I not should choose a Id of a class first. It should print the classname everytime the class doesnt have the course.

Comment: That's not the question you asked in your post. ^^

To get the classes that don't have course x: `SELECT Name FROM Classes WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id from Activitys WHERE CourseId = <ID from Course x>)`